# Is there any callback by system before static variables are destroyed caused by Home pressed

Tags: android

I have the following piece of code in `Activity`

```
// Cache object is holding other resources like thread handle, file handle.
// Explicit clean up is required when it is no longer used.
public static Cache cache = new Cache();

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (this.isFinishing()) {
        cache.cleanUp();
    }
}
```

Note that, I need to have `isFinishing` check, as having phone rotation, home press, launching new activity... will trigger `onPause` as well. So, having the cleanup cache due to such "simple" operation defeat the purpose of having Cache object.

However, there is a possibility of resource leakage in my design.

1. Run the app
2. Press Home
3. Run other memory intensive app by running them, pressing Home, running the others again.
4. At some point, system discovers it should remove my app as it is not activated for quite some time. Hence, `cache` will become null. **However, I have no chance to call cache.cleanUp**
5. Long press on Home button. My app should still appear in the list.
6. Select it. The activity will onCreate again, and 2nd instance of static cache will be created again.

In such case, we are having resource leak, as the previous allocated old thread handles, file handles owned by 1st cache object, are still in the system. We have no way to deal-locate them, because the 1st cache object is destroyed by the system.

I wish there is a callback by system, whenever the system decide to destroy my app due to home pressed. With such callback, I can perform necessary clean up call on my static objects, before they are being destroyed.

May I know how I can achieve so?

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you mean your app is destroyed or your Activity?  If the app is destroyed, then there can be no leaks (unless there are bugs in the GC - but that would apply for all apps).  If the Activity is destroyed, then onPause() must have been called since your Activity will only be destroyed if it is not in the foreground.  I don't understand your issue.

Answer (score 1):

> In such case, we are having resource leak, as the previous allocated
>   old thread handles, file handles owned by 1st cache object, are still
>   in the system

GC will take care of it. Thats the reason your app is killed. So that such memory gets cleaned up and used by other apps.

Comment: Those are thread handles and files handles. You need to stop thread explicitly, and close file explicitly. GC only responsible for memory.

Comment: To add, if parent reference (cache) becomes null, child references will become unreachable and later garbage collected.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng If the app is destroyed, all handles and threads it owns will also be released.  The GC will get them at some point.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(cache!=null) {
    cache.cleanUp();
}
```

It is better you assume the logic that **"I will do this and this only if cache is not null"**.

Comment: cache will never be null within application code scope, and that's not the current problem described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no callback method for Home key press.  If you want to destroy your apps on Home key press, better set a static variable on back key press(onKeyUp and if keycode==back_key). and onPause method, if that variable is not set then destroy that activity (finish();).

**Long press on Home button. My app should still appear in the list.On**  :: that list for recent activity its not depend on killing your activity etc...